# DataGrab fails if not run from EE Control Panel (logged in)

Tags: sessions, datagrab

We've had an odd issue with a new site that's running DataGrab via CRON on EE2 that I'm really hoping someone can help with.

Everything was working fine for the first few weeks and data was being fed through automatically every 10 minutes. However, we recently noticed that our import URL had stopped working for no apparent reason. Debugging the URL, we receive the following error:

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
Line Number: 442
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/********/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 475
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column ‘Array’ in ‘where clause’
SELECT * FROM (exp_member_groups) WHERE group_id = Array
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 369`

The feed runs successfully within the EE control panel and the Import URL also works if logged into EE. However, when ***not*** logged in, the Import URL fails. We’ve tried re-installing and re-configuring DataGrab but that hasn’t made any difference. I can't think of any changes we've made to EE that would have caused the Import URL to start failing.

So my main question is: Can anyone think of a setting within EE that could cause DataGrab to stop working if not logged in? Anything to do with Sessions?

FYI, I have a back-up version from a few weeks ago running on the same server which still works perfectly. I've spent time going through the Control Panel screens trying to compare settings and find something that's different but I can't see any anomalies.

I'm kinda out of ideas on things to try and haven't had a reply from DataGrab's developer.

Really hope someone can help.

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Wild guess as errors similar to this have happened on a few of my sites. Double check the php hasn't been uograded on the server. Some hosts seem to update without notification.

Comment: Thanks @stuartmcd69. I actually have a version of the site running on the same server (same PHP etc) which does work. It's so odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into this issue as well, I don't know if this will resolve your issue.

It tries to create a session for a member with a member_id of 1, do you have a member with an id of 1 that belongs to the group id 1? If not, change a member with superadmin group id 1 access to a member_id of 1.

```
function _check_member_status() {

    // If not currently logged in, create a dummy session
    // @todo: currently hard-coded, need to search db for admin user?
    $this->current_user = $this->session->userdata['member_id'];
    if( $this->session->userdata['member_id'] == 0) {
        $this->session->create_new_session(1, TRUE);
        //$this->session->userdata['username']  = "dummy";
        $this->session->userdata['group_id']  = 1;
        $this->session->userdata['can_edit_other_entries'] = 'y';
        $this->session->userdata['can_delete_self_entries'] = 'y';
        $this->session->userdata['can_delete_all_entries'] = 'y';
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Brad. You're right, this was the issue...though I actually figured it out a few weeks ago but got so wrapped up in other projects I forgot to update this thread. The user with ID 1 had been deleted from the system. Adding one back in fix the issue.